# In Parent child relationship, for grand child if I give parent as routing will it sits in the Super parent shard?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have parent child implementation, For Super parent I wont give the routing and for child will give super parent id as routing so it will sit in the same shard. And for grand child I will give its parent id as routing(I dont want to give super parent as routing)
My concern is will the grand child will sit in the Super parent shard by finding its parent and then parent.s parent shard?

Answer (score 1):

Grandchildren will not be on the same shard. You MUST specify the 'super' for routing:

```
PUT /<index>/<type>/<id>?parent=<parent_id>&routing=<super_id>
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/grandparents.html